# How to resolve it if my swagger UI (generated by spring Boot) is not showing request body for x-www-form-urlencoded body?

Tags: spring, api, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am looking at swagger UI auto-generated by spring boot. In my API i have mentioned

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
```

But in the UI Swagger doesn't show me an option to hit it entering the parameters from UI itself and i have to shift to postman. I don't know how is this file generated, whether it involves OAS yaml file as well, so i don't know where am I missing code changes?

Comment: Can you post the full annotations, a screenshot of Swagger UI, and the OpenAPI definition file (YAML or JSON) generated from the annotations?

Comment: I don't know where the OAS file would be, but I'm sharing the method in spring with all annotations. and the screenshot after trying a solution: Start of this method is like this-

Comment: @PostMapping(value="/uploadRiskContract/v1.0/contracts",  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload risk contract." , tags = { API_TAG_STAGE_BUILD } ,response = MasterContractResponseVO.class)

Comment: Then I added implicit Params like this:

Comment: ```
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "gpm", value = "String from Uploaded GPM XML", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "actionBy", value = "ActionBy", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "actionRole", value = "ActionRole", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    })
  ```